# Is there are way to return the collision pair which are in collision in Bullet?

Tags: c++, simulation, game-physics, mesh, bulletphysics

I am currently building a simulation software for robotics. I am using bullet physics to perform collision detection and for robot rigid body dynamics.

I am able to successfully detect when two triangle collision meshes collide with each other. Now I would like to highlight the collision pair by changing the colour of the mesh to red when collision happens. To do so, I need to know which two meshes are colliding. Is there a way to return the collision pair which is in collision in Bullet?

I have looked through the Bullet Physics documentation and could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

At collision object creation, you're able to set the `CollisionObject.UserObject` with an id, name,... or the mesh itself.

If you're using a custom `ContactResultCallback`, you will get the collided objects and the collision points as parameters of the `AddSingleResult()` method. The previously set user object could now help you to identify the collided meshes:

```
/// <inheritdoc cref="ContactResultCallback"/>
public override double AddSingleResult(ManifoldPoint manifoldPoint,
                                       CollisionObjectWrapper collisionObjectWrapper1,
                                       int partId1,
                                       int index1,
                                       CollisionObjectWrapper collisionObjectWrapper2,
                                       int partId2,
                                       int index2)
{
    var mesh1 = collisionObjectWrapper1.CollisionObject.UserObject as Mesh;
    var mesh2 = collisionObjectWrapper2.CollisionObject.UserObject as Mesh;

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

If you're working with `CollisionWorld.StepSimulate(...)` and `CollisionWorld.SetInternalTickCallback(OnSimualtionTick)` for "live" collision detection, you will also get the user objects:

```
private void OnSimualtionTick(DynamicsWorld world, float timeStep)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < world.Dispatcher.NumManifolds; i++)
    {
        PersistentManifold contactManifold = world.Dispatcher.GetManifoldByIndexInternal(i);
        var mesh1 = contactManifold.Body0.UserObject as Mesh;
        var mesh2 = contactManifold.Body1.UserObject as Mesh;

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```